# Add "webforms like" values to profile.module select list

Tags: webforms, users

Is there a module that can allow me to add custom values to select list items in the Profiles module in Drupal 6, like webforms does it. For example:

```
my_value_1 | my_text_1
my_value_2 | my_text_2
```

which will create a select list

```
<select>
<option value="my_value_1">my_text_1</option>
<option value="my_value_2">my_text_2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) module. Using this module you can create user profile where you can add cck fields to the user profile content type.

> This module builds user profiles as content (aka nodes), which opens
>   the opportunity to use all the powerful modules for content for user
>   profiles too, e.g. the Content Construction Kit (CCK). It's intended
>   to be simple and useful, but extensible by further modules.

Comment: I just want to add key|value pairs. Why is everything so difficult in Drupal? With Content Profile I have to add 2 modules, change all my profile settings etc etc. Isn't there any other way? Programmatically? I can see the fields in the database table.